# How often is Postgres parsing a foreign table based on file_fdw?

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-fdw

I have a foreign table defined with file_fdw, which reads the data from a CSV file. Postgresql parses the CSV file and converts the date for example from `YYYYMMDD` to `YYYY-MM-DD`. This works fine.

My question is how often gets the CSV file parsed? Does it get parsed on every `select`? Or does it get cached? And if so how long does it get cached?

Comment: There is no caching for this,  they get parsed every time,  this is one of the reason why FDW can be a bottle neck for performance as the server has no means to track what is happening externally so it must re-query the remote data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is read whenever the foreign table is scanned, which can happen several times during processing of a query.

There is no caching except the file system cache of the operating system.